# If I have Succ<T> can I create type LessThan<T>?

Tags: typescript, types

I have type alias `Succ<T extends 0|1|2|3|...|99>`. Which returns next number.

For example:

```js
type A = Succ<10> // A = 11
```

Can I define some type that will behave in such way:

```js
type LessThan<T> = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | (T - 1)
```

If I can, how?

I want to avoid description of the result for each individual number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot currently do type-level arithmetic with `number` types in a straightforward way.  There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) (and maybe others) asking for this.

If you can't add or subtract *numbers*, yet, you can at least grow and shrink *tuples*, by using TS4.0's [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) and TS4.1's [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types).  So one idea is to generate a bunch of tuples like `[0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0]` of lengths up to the number you care about, and then get the `length` property of them to convert back into the `number`s you care about.

The only problem here is how to do it in a way that won't run afoul of TypeScript's recursion limits or otherwise destroy compiler performance.  If you concatenate tuples one element at a time, you will find that `LessThan<20>` will be too taxing on the compiler.  Here's one possible approach, but I don't know that it's worth the effort:

```
type TuplesOfLengthsUpToAndBeyond<N extends number, T extends 0[] = [0]> =
  T[N] extends undefined ? (
    TuplesOfLengthsUpToAndBeyond<N, [...T, ...T]> |
    [...T, ...TuplesOfLengthsUpToAndBeyond<N, [...T, ...T]>]
  ) : []

type LessThanOrEqual<N extends number> =
  TuplesOfLengthsUpToAndBeyond<N> extends infer O ? O extends any[] ?
  O[N] extends undefined ? O['length'] :
  never : never : never;

type LessThan<N extends number> = Exclude<LessThanOrEqual<N>, N>;
```

The `TuplesOfLengthsUpToAndBeyond<N>` type gets around the one-element-at-a-time problem by creating exponentially larger unions of tuples, where each recursion level tends to double the length of the tuples involved.  `TuplesOfLengthUpToAndBeyond<4>` gives (I think) the union `[] | [0] | [0, 0] | ... | [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` of all tuples less than or equal to 8 elements long.  In general given `N` you get tuples up to some power of two greater than or equal to `N`.

Then, `LessThanOrEqual<N>` filters this list and removes everything whose length is greater than `N`, and returns the union of `length` properties.  This is very close to what you want except that it will include `N`.

So `LessThan<N>` just `Exclude`s `N` from that.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
type LessThan6 = LessThan<6> // 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

type LessThan100 = LessThan<100>
/* type LessThan100 = 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 16 | 32 | 64 | 96 | 48 | 80 | 24 | 40 | 72 | 56 | 
 88 | 12 | 20 | 36 | 68 | 52 | 84 | 28 | 44 | 76 | 60 | 92 | 6 | 10 | 18 | 34 | 66 | 
 98 | 50 | 82 | 26 | 42 | 74 | 58 | 90 | 14 | 22 | ... 57 more ... | 95 */
```

That's all fine and the compiler seems to act okay.  It gets past the `15` or `20` limit without a problem. Unfortunately, this still doesn't scale very well.  If you try `LessThan<1000>`, it *eventually* works:

```
type LessThan1000 = LessThan<1000> // ⏳
/* type LessThan1000 = 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 16 | 32 | 64 | 128 | 256 | 512 | 768 
 | 384 | 640 | 896 | 192 | 320 | 576 | 832 | 448 | 704 | 960 | 96 | 160 | 288 | 544
 | 800 | 416 | 672 | 928 | 224 | 352 | 608 | 864 | 480 | ... 964 more ... | 767 */
```

but it takes a noticeable amount of time to work... like ten or so seconds on my machine.  That's probably not great.  Ideally a computer should be able to spit out the list of all numbers less than `1000` in... essentially no time at all.  So until microsoft/TypeScript#26382 or something like it comes out, you might want to rethink the need for this.  You may or may not want to hard-code your own union list.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAzgeQGYBkIDsDmwAFigKpgwD2AgrgCYBCEIl9APAHJQQAewedFFFxwAtgCMIAJwA0sbnwFCADAG0AulAC8UVcvUA+bQCgosVR029+9IXHoQMAS1wQ6UAPxQAFKbOwEZHRsPEIScipaRmZWOk45VQA6ZJg5ZMSYQygAHz8zJJS0lMDUTBwCYjIKGnomFnYOBPTUqGbDdT8ASigALl0O41BIKBwUFBgiAENcNCkAUQBHOEnETgUbQWExSSkjLT94JFKQivDqqLrYziNrJSgXDGkoNE9n9bvpkA1PPzQLK0Utig9jojhcblefwA5MhTlDND0-K4AG5PPootHCCCoqQAbmMg3A0FG4ymuDWtyBIgk0j2UDmPAAxog4KC2CSJtNZotlqsOAY5Pz8YThhyyQA2bQjVCk6ZscVGAD0iqgyhyUAAjOqAEzqgDM6oALOqAKwEobEmWc3Aa5RqnRiuW25QGYyKgBUUAt0rG1udUrV2U1OqN6oAHOqNZKg3rdUHxcagwBOaNQQ0RoNhwNQbWJtPZgDscagJtTpjDGc1xe12b1qfFlZNxbDee1lcNeYL9ezSeLqdtkcrerz4rLUCTjezYerqcNxYLeZNlaT2Y1reL6RLBagokoUmgm+TJqg7sVBOV3sdNrt9p9svJzpdUGVUEAz8Ruz2Xq1kx8ByMhoM80rKN9T7PMNTbHVS1NCD1S7CNTBjFt1QTKcU0jXtQOzE0u3DWMjXTODlDzFMe37cVszbRsO0QqAs2zQ0QPjIt1V7SttVzfUmxQ5RKzDBMjSzdVNxTY1d33Vpkjg8Vt1PIA)

Comment: Intersting that now it seems to work fast, at least on my PC on this playground link

Comment: Yes, it is amazing @jcalz